# Get Calendar info on event drop between multiple calendars vuejs

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar in vue.js. I have implemented multiple calendars dynamically when i dropped event from one calendar to another calendar it is working fine but how can i know on which calendar i have dropped the event because i want to update it in database. I am not finding any way to do this. Is there any way to handle this.

Here is the code that of calendar component

```
<div class='demo-app col' v-for="(staff, index) in staffData" v-bind:key="staff.id">
<h5 class="text-center">{{staff.name}}</h5>
<FullCalendar
  class='demo-app-calendar'
  ref="fullCalendar"
  defaultView="timeGridDay"
  height="auto"
  :header="{
    left: '',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
  }"
  :plugins="calendarPlugins"
  :weekends="calendarWeekends"
  :events="appointments[index]"
  :editable="true"
  :eventResourceEditable="true"
  :selectMirror="true"
  :droppable="true"
  :slotEventOverlap="false"


  @dateClick="handleDateClick"      
  @eventReceive="onEventReceive"
  @eventLeave="onEventLeave"
  @drop="onEventDrop"
  />
  </div>
```

---

```
getAppointments(){

       var promises = [];

        this.staffData.forEach(function(staff){
          var myUrl = '<url>'+ staff.id;
          promises.push(axios.get(myUrl))
        });

        axios.all(promises).then(results => {
            results.forEach(response => {
                console.log(response.data.data);
                this.appointments.push(response.data.data);

            })
        });        
}
```

---

here is the documentation
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive

Comment: Please read [ask]. Without a [mcve] or at least the relevant parts of your code, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i have added a code example

Comment: where is your "onEventReceive" code?